# Firefox : Any settings/addon to load few favorite sites when firefox starts?

Tags: firefox

I want firefox to load a set of favorite site every time firefox is started.

Any settings / addon which can help me ?

Comment: Look for the "Use Current Pages" option, right there by the Home Page setting.

Answer (score 5):

[Automatically Open Multiple Tabs with your Favorite Websites on Start up in Firefox](http://www.aboutonlinetips.com/open-multiple-tabs-on-start-up-in-firefox/)

Answer (score 4):

This has been built-in for a while. First open the sites in tabs. When you have the set you'd like to start with just head over to Options. In the "Main" section click "Use Current Pages" and Firefox will save 'em all as your starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There is an Add On called [Morning Coffee.](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2677) You specify what pages to open on which day of the week, or whether the page should be opened every day. It puts a little button on the bar with all the other browser buttons. Click it and it launches all the sites specified for that day of the week.

I like it and have used it.

Hope that helps 
:)

Answer (score 1):

In Tools -> options -> general tab -> startup:

Have your different homepages separated by a pipe "|", eg if you wanted both google and yahoo as your homepages:

```
http://www.google.com/ | http://www.yahoo.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave this pages open and set Save on close, so it will open'em after you boot Forefox

Comment: I might have kept other sites as well open and while closing the firefox I don't want to close those tabs one by one and leave the needed sites to load next times I restart firefox.

Answer (score 0):

This addon might be overkill in your case but i'll mention it anyways: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2324.

With the help of Session manager you can create sessions and set one as the session to use at startup.